# population of texboxes when combobox selected item is changed

Tags: c#

Hello all I am trying to populate some textboxes automatically when I select an item from a combobox dropdown list using Microsoft sql server with a usercontrol form. I have written the codes below, however I am getting the items in the combox dropdown list but when I select an item in the combobox dropdown list, nothing happens in the text boxes. the values are in a table called competitors. the columns are Institution, Region, FirstName, LastName and I want the values to display in the respective textboxes when I select the combox dropdown. I seek your assistance in solving this problem. thanks in advance

```
    private void RabbitCare_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CBoxParishDdlist.Items.Clear();
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ITSPECIALIST\SQLPROJECTS;Initial Catalog=EXPRORESULTS;Integrated Security=True ");
        connect.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = connect.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "Select ParishName FROM Competitors WHERE CompetitiveEventName = 'Care and Management of Bees'";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dat = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        SDA.Fill(dat);
        foreach (DataRow DAR in dat.Rows)
        {
            CBoxParishDdlist.Items.Add(DAR["ParishName"].ToString());
        }
        connect.Close();
    }

    private void CBoxParishDdlist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ITSPECIALIST\SQLPROJECTS;Initial Catalog=EXPRORESULTS;Integrated Security=True ");
            connect.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM  Competitors WHERE ParishName = '" + CBoxParishDdlist.Text + "'", connect);



            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {

                string Institution = (string)dr["Institution"].ToString();
                TxtBoxInstitution.Text = Institution;

                string Region = (string)dr["Region"].ToString();
                TxtBoxRegion.Text = Region;

                string FirstName = (string)dr["FirstName"].ToString();
                TxtBoxFname.Text = FirstName;

                string LastName = (string)dr["LastName"].ToString();
                TxtBoxLname.Text = LastName;

            }
            connect.Close();
```

Comment: Did you debug your code? Did you check if while loop is executing or not?

Comment: I did debug and no error was shown. not sure how to check if while looping is executing

Comment: The code written inside while loop gets executed?

Comment: it didn't has the values were not displayed in the textboxes

Comment: That means the data is not returned from the db. Try running the same query against the database directly from sql management studio and see if you get any results

Comment: I got the results from the database directly

Comment: Then only debugging is the way to figure out the issue. Your code looks fine. If data is returning from database then it should display in textboxes. There is no obvious mistake i can see in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem.

```
TxtBoxInstitution.Text = comboBoxName.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Comment: I tried this but still nothing showing up in the textboxes